# Is my HDD failing?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure, bad-blocks, drive-health

I tried to resize a partition of my 3-year-old HDD using gparted, but it failed and displayed a message saying that there were bad blocks and that was a sign of physical damage to the drive.

I used badblocks to check for bad blocks, and there are exactly 4 of them.

smartctl shows me this:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       568
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   135   133   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4241
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1290
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   086   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       10357
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1278
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       363
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       926
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   111   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

Is my drive already failing?

Comment: "Is my drive already failing?" - Yes

Answer (score 1):

SMART data without the drive manufacturer / model is often close to useless information as each manufacturer gathers, processes and presents data in different ways. So give us the full SMART thing.

That being said:

```
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
```

There is one sector 'pending' which means the drive had a problem accessing it / reading it. And this may very well be the problem sector you're resizing tool was complaining about.

Just one problematic sector in general isn't something that would lead to the conclusion a drive is failing. But this is one sector the drive *knows* about, it does not tell us if there are possibly more.

Using a tool like [Victoria for Windows](https://hdd.by/victoria/) may help determine if there are more of such sectors and can also help getting them reallocated, using the surface scan feature.

[image]

As we should always consider the drive is in the process of failing, surface scans are potentially the last straw, so make sure to back up important data first. As @ramhound comments, yes the hard drive is failing, because all hard drives are from the moment you start using them (I am assuming this is what he means).

---

EDIT: I didn't notice the linux tag, sorry. For a surface scan that detects bad sector and writes to a detected bad sector to force reallocation, any tool can be used that:

- Read sector x
- read OK -> continue with sector x + 1
- read bad -> write to sector x (sector worth of zeros) -> read sector x -> good read: successfully remapped
- etc.